# Istanbul Code Coverage information access from Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, istanbul

**Context**

I am developing [living-tests](https://github.com/still-dreaming-1/living-tests) for Node.js. In that context I am not so much interested in how things are normally done, but how they can be done better, so by necessity different.

**Problem**

From a javascript test script, I want to be able to specify what some test code is intended to cover. So let's say I have a `File` prototype, and I want to test the `path` property. Just before the code that exercises this property, I want to in some way specify that is what is being tested. Then after that code runs, I want to specify it is completed. In between those points, when the code is being exercised, I don't want to count any of the code coverage that covered anything else other than that property. This way a developer can ensure something was not merely covered incidentally, which can help developers to understand about what they have and have not thoroughly tested. This is intended to partially address the issue of code coverage not necessarily meaning something is well tested.

**Approach**

As far as I can tell, Istanbul is the only commonly used and recommended code coverage tool for javascript, so I am currently forcusing on using that tool. I know you have to start Istanbul before you start node, so it can instrument your code. However, I suspect that as long as that has been done, the code that is running in node should be able to access code coverage information about what has been covered so far. I'm pretty sure if I can do that I can figure out how to use it to accomplish what I want.

How can I access code coverage information from javascript?

Comment: [blanket.js](http://blanketjs.org/) exists as well. I've used it once before, unsure if it will be helpful in your case.

Comment: @clay Thanks. I am saving blanket.js as a last resort because it is not a maintained project.

Comment: Judging from the answers / comments so far the question itself can be interpreted in different ways. Let me paraphrase to check if I get it: Given a specific test, only consider code that was intentionally tested as being covered. This would imply that you reference your test-case within a comment around the relevent code to be tested. If and only if a test runs code that is specifically designated to belong to this test via this comment, consider it covered. Right?

Comment: It seems if I only ask what I want to know people complain they don't understand what problem I am actually trying to solve, but when I provide context they complain this makes the question interpretable...

Comment: I just want to be get access to what has been covered so far. Hopefully I could figure out the rest from there.

Answer (score 2):

The question is asking for something that doesn't solve the problem...

You can access the information from coverage.json after triggering the code coverage run. See https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/blob/master/coverage.json.md

But what you need, I think, is some other algorithm. You specify it as "I want to *in some way* specify that is what is being tested." which is unfortunately too vague to recommend anything.

Code coverage tools just watch what gets executed during tests and mark everything else as "untested". No more logic there.

Comment: Exactly so. Even if you strip all asserts away from your test code, the test coverage still remains the same.

Comment: I love how any time I leave anything about anything on here vague, people hone in on that. I intentionally left that part vague because it is not the point of the question. I can't know how I want to do that until I know what resources are made available to see the code coverage.

Comment: You said I can access the information from coverage.json after triggering the code coverage run. But can I access it after I trigger the run and before it finishes running to see what has been covered so far?

Comment: What is coverage.json? I don't see a coverage.json.

Comment: 1) coverage.json = the report from istanbul. The HTML it also generates is just graphical representation. See docs. 2) I'm pretty sure it's written only after the run is at the end. 3) I'm far from scolding you for being vague, instead I'd like to know what you mean exactly, so that I could help you...

Comment: I'm confused about which Istanbul project is the one most people are actually using. There is the one you linked to, which is the first one that comes up when I google Istanbul code coverage, and then there is https://istanbul.js.org/ which links to https://github.com/istanbuljs. As far as I can tell they are completely unrelated...

Comment: If the end report is json or html, I want a way to tell Istanbul when to stop tracking and generate a report at some point in the code, preferably by calling some Istanbul function on that line where it should stop. Then I want to tell it to start generating a new report with new coverage information starting at some other point. Basically I want to communicate with Istanbul from the script with the tests in it.

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 From what I understand `nyc`/the `istanbuljs` org is an improved version of `istanbul`. I think plans are to deprecate `istanbul` when `nyc` is stable enough.

Comment: @pkopac I went ahead and gave you the bounty points since you at least pointed me to a json file where code coverage information is provided as well as the documentation for that. JSON is a format that is commonly used as a data source in javascript, so potentially I could have some javascript code that uses that code coverage information in some way.

Comment: @RyanZim The information I have found on this seems to confirm what you are saying. I think you are right. So basically it seems the Istanbul linked to in this answer is currently still the "official" one, but it will be deprecated at some point.